# Detecting Joystick buttons

Tags: autohotkey

I have this simple script where if a button is pressed I display a message. Pretty simple script but even though I pressing the right button nothing shows up on my screen.

```
Joy1::
MsgBox, Joy1

Joy2::
MsgBox, Joy2

Joy3::
MsgBox, Joy3

Joy4::
MsgBox, Joy4

Joy5::
MsgBox, Joy5
```

Here is a proof that I'm actually pressing the buttons, in this case 1 and 2.

[image]

Comment: I don't have any experience with joysticks, but maybe [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RemapJoystick.htm) documentation page could be of help?

Comment: I pretty much tried most of those examples, none of them worked. I don't understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its due to AutoHotkey using an old API to detect the keys, at least with windows 10, [reference](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=61413). It does detect them if an AutoHotkey window is active, like when you right click on the AutoHotkey icon and select 'Open'. I was also able to cook something up with the xinput [library](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ky3wx5stj0uoj9/XInput.ahk?dl=0) by Lexikos, and some posts from that forum [topic](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/35848-xinput-xbox-360-controller-api/), the below makes a MsgBox when 'a' is pressed on my controller(xbox one).

```
#Include path to xinput.ahk

SetTimer, checkForJoy1, 100

checkForJoy1:
XInput_Init()
state := Xinput_GetState(0)
if(state) {
    a_pressed := state.wButtons & 4096
    if(a_pressed) {
        Msgbox, Does this work [%a_pressed%]
    }
}

return
```